# Cannot set values from a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to a bound DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I am having a DataGridView that initially loads data and shows it.
When an user clicks an Edit Button, I am adding a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn by hiding one of the Columns.

```
private DataTable BindCombo()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ProductId", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "Product1");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Product2");
    return dt;
}

private void BindGrid()
{
   DataTable dtGrid = new DataTable();
   DataColumn column = new DataColumn("ProductId")
   {
      DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"),
      AutoIncrement = true,
      AutoIncrementSeed = 1,
      AutoIncrementStep = 1
   };
   dtGrid.Columns.Add(column);
   dtGrid.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));

   dtGrid.Rows.Add(null, "Product1");
   dtGrid.Rows.Add(null, "Product2");

   dataGridView1.DataSource = dtGrid;
 }

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    BindGrid();
 }
```

Here is the `Button.Click` event where I am trying to add a ComboBox Column:

```
 private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
     dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
     dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
     DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
     {
         DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.DropDownButton,
         HeaderText = "Product Name",
         DataSource = BindCombo(),
         ValueMember = "ProductId",
         DisplayMember = "ProductName",
         DataPropertyName = "ProductId"
     };
     dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col1);
     dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }
```

When I click on drop down, nothing happens:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataTable used as the DataSource of your DataGridView has an auto-increment Column. You cannot use this Column as the `ProductId`, which can be changed by an User via the ComboBox selector. It will make a mess (unless this was used just just to build a MCVE).
You can use this Column as the Primary Key - setting also `Unique = true`.

Add instead a `int` Column that represents the `ProductId` Key, which links the `ProductName` Column that is part of the DataTable set as the DataSource of the ComboBox Column.
Since the `ValueMember` property of the ComboBox is set to the `ProductId` value and the ComboBox Column is bound to the `ProductId` Column of the DataGridView DataTable, changing the SelectdItem of the ComboBox will change the value of the `ProductId` Column of the DataTable used as data source of your DataGridView.

Added to the **`BindProductsGrid()`** method:

- `dtGrid.PrimaryKey = new[] { pkColumn };`
- `dtGrid.AcceptChanges();` (mandatory)
- `dgvProducts.Columns["ProductId"].ReadOnly = true;` and
- `dgvProducts.AllowUserToAddRows = false;` (since this seems to be the intention: let the User specify the Product only using the ComboBox selector)

The `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` is added after the DataSource of the DataGridView is set. This because this Column is bound to the `ProductId` Column, as the corresponding Column of the DataGridView's DataTable.
It allows to add to the DataGridView two Columns bound to the same Column of the data source in code, without *confusing* the Control.

```
private void BindProductsGrid()
{
    var dtGrid = new DataTable();
    var pkColumn = new DataColumn("ID") {
        DataType = typeof(int),
        AutoIncrement = true,
        AutoIncrementSeed = 1,
        AutoIncrementStep = 1,
        Unique = true
    };

    var productColumn = new DataColumn("ProductId") {
        DataType = typeof(int),
        Caption = "Product Id"
    };

    dtGrid.Columns.Add(pkColumn);
    dtGrid.Columns.Add(productColumn);

    dtGrid.Rows.Add(null, 1);
    dtGrid.Rows.Add(null, 2);
    dtGrid.Rows.Add(null, 3);
    dtGrid.Rows.Add(null, 4);

    dtGrid.PrimaryKey = new[] { pkColumn };
    dtGrid.AcceptChanges();

    dgvProducts.DataSource = dtGrid;

    dgvProducts.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
    dgvProducts.Columns["ProductId"].ReadOnly = true;

    var productName = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn {
        DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing,
        Name = "ProductName",
        HeaderText = "Product Name",
        ValueMember = "ProductId",
        DisplayMember = "ProductName",
        DataSource = BindCombo(),
        DataPropertyName = "ProductId",
        DisplayIndex = 2
    };
    dgvProducts.Columns.Add(productName);
    dgvProducts.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
}
```

The DataTable used as data source of the ComboBox has the same two Columns, just `AcceptChanges()` (optional) is added to the previous code:

```
private DataTable BindCombo()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ProductId", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));

    dt.Rows.Add(1, "Product1");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Product2");
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Product3");
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "Product4");
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    return dt;
}
```

Now, some adjustments to make the Product selection more *responsive*:
(➨ note that the DataGridView is named **`dgvProducts`**)

- The `EditingControlShowing` handler subscribes to the ComboBox Cell `SelectedIndexChanged` event
- The ComboBox `SelectedIndexChanged` handler invokes asynchronously `Validate()`, to show the ComboBox selection immediately (no need to select another Cell to see it applied)

  ```
  BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Validate()));
  ```
- The DataGridView `CellContentClick` handler changes the style of the ComboBox to `DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox`
- `CellLeave` handler restores the ComboBox style to `DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing`, so it looks like a TextBox.

▶ If you instead want to just hide/show the `ProductName` column, you can do without the `CellContentClick` and `CellLeave` handlers and keep the initial ComboBox style.

```
private void dgvComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndexChanged -= dgvComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Validate()));
}

private void dgvProducts_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control is ComboBox cbo) {
        cbo.SelectedIndexChanged += dgvComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }
}

private void dgvProducts_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex > 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 2) {
        if (dgvProducts[2, e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbox) {
            cbox.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox;
        }
    }
}

private void dgvProducts_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0) return;
    if (dgvProducts.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "ProductName") {
        if (dgvProducts["ProductName", e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbox) {
            cbox.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
        }
    }
}
```

This how it works using the code shown here:

[image: DataGridView ComboBoxColumn Selector]